# malloc() call does not persist across functions

Tags: c, malloc

Code:

```
struct Adjacent {
    char* c;
    int done_at; 
};

typedef struct Adjacent Adj; 

struct Container {
    Adj* m;
};

typedef struct Container Cont;

void alloc_stuff(Cont *cont) {
    cont = (Cont*)malloc(100 * sizeof(Cont));
    memset(cont, 0, 100 * sizeof(Cont));
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        cont[i].m = (Adj*)malloc(50 * sizeof(Adj));
        memset(cont[i].m, 0, 50 * sizeof(Adj));
        cont[i].m->c = (char*)malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
        memset(cont[i].m->c, 0, 50 * sizeof(char));
        cont[i].m->done_at = 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    Cont* cont = NULL;

    alloc_stuff(cont);

    // cont still NULL here
}
```

Why is `cont` NULL after `alloc_stuff()`?

Comment: It is NULL because you didn't change it.  Change your API and either do `alloc_stuff(&cont);` or `cont = alloc_stuff();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`alloc_stuff(cont);` passes the value of `cont` to `alloc_stuff`.

`alloc_stuff` does not receive any reference to `cont`. No changes made inside `alloc_stuff` can affect `cont`.

To change the value of `cont` in `main`, you should either modify `alloc_stuff` to return a pointer and use `cont = alloc_stuff();`, or you should modify `alloc_stuff` to accept a pointer to `Cont *` (so it would be a `Cont **`) and then modify the code inside it to use `*cont` where it is current using `cont`, after which you can call it with `alloc_stuff(&cont);`. (Or, where parentheses are needed, use `(*cont)` in place of `cont`.)

Comment: `*cont[i]->m = (Adj*)malloc(50 * sizeof(Adj));` gives `no operator = matches these operands. Operands are Adj and Adj* even though Cont has Adj* and not Adj (no pointer)

Comment: @Sebi: Use parentheses as noted in the answer. `[` has higher precedence than `*`, so you need `(*cont)[i]->m`, not `*cont[i]->m`. Also, that error message suggests you are compiling as C++, not. Those are different languages and have different rules. A reference to a pointer might be more appropriate in C++ than a pointer to a pointer, and it would avoid the need for changing the code inside `alloc_stuff`; you would only need to change the declaration.

Comment: Yes, I'm compiling as C++.  `(*cont)[i]->m = (Adj*)malloc(50 * sizeof(Adj));` gives expression must have a pointer type. How does the syntax change (ref 2 pointer)?

Comment: Nvm (*cont)[i]->m is of type Adj&. (*cont)[i].m is Adj*

Answer (score 3):

It is because of this line:

```
void alloc_stuff(Cont *cont)
```

The variable cont is a copy of the original pointer passed to the function.

If you want to modify the original pointer, you should use something like this:

```
void alloc_stuff(Cont **cont)
```